# gulp: browserify/babelify build script, unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify

I am currently trying to enhance my ReactJS application by adding https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment I installed it via `npm install input-moment --save` and I am importing it using `import InputMoment from 'input-moment'`.

But it seems that my custom build script does not compile it, but tries to source the react-style version directly. [edit: Noticed by compile error "unexpected token" on React-style html tags)]

Can you help me fix my build script, so including un-transformed files works, too?

Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
// TODO: Get this to work.
require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname);

var gulp       = require('gulp');
var source     = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify   = require('babelify');
var watchify   = require('watchify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var streamify  = require('gulp-streamify');
var uglify     = require('gulp-uglify');
var sass       = require('gulp-sass');
var gutil      = require('gulp-util');
var notify     = require('gulp-notify');

function handleErrors() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    notify.onError({
        title: 'Compile Error',
        message: '<%= error.message %>'
    }).apply(this, args);
    this.emit('end'); // Keep gulp from hanging on this task
}

function buildScript(file, watch) {
    var props = {
        entries: ['./app/'+file],
        debug: true,
        transform:  [babelify],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        fullPaths: true
    };

    // watchify() if watch requested, otherwise run browserify() once
    var bundler = watch ? watchify(browserify(props)) : browserify(props);

    function rebundle() {
        var stream = bundler.bundle();
        return stream
            .on('error', handleErrors)
            .pipe(source(file))
            // .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
    }

    // listen for an update and run rebundle
    bundler.on('update', function() {
        rebundle();
        gutil.log('Rebundle ...');
    });

    // run it once the first time buildScript is called
    return rebundle();
};

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return buildScript('app.jsx', true);
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass', 'sass:watch']);
```

Additionally, I'm using the following .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports"
  ]
}
```

So far it worked fine and I have a lot of modules running, but this is the first that seems to be uncompiled in node_modules.

Comment: browserify doesn't transform files inside node_modules, unless the package (inside node_modules) explicitly says so. The npm package you are loading should be precompiled.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for your answer. I see there's a dist folder inside the node module. When importing from there it compiles, but it does not work as I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React" - any idea why? I'm issuing this as a ticket on GitHub, maybe it's an error in code?